# How is the indexing method works in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I was doing numpy problems and there was a question about this array.

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25]
 [26 27 28 29 30]]
```

I have to get 11, 12, 16, 17. The solution is to index the array as `[2:4, 0:2]`. How does this work? I was expecting something along the lines of `[2, :3]` for the `[11, 12]` and `[3, :2]` for `[16, 17]`.

Comment: First is the rows you want, ending exclusive (so 2 and 3), the second is which columns of them (so 0 and 1)

Comment: If the values are vertically aligned, why do you expect different column indices for `[11,12]` and `[16,17]`?

Comment: Although I may be wrong, I think its the syntax he is asking about — i.e. how do the internals work, when NumPy is not built-in to Python, how can it allow such a syntax?

Comment: Why not `[2, :2]` for the first?  `:2` appplies to both.  At what level `how` do you need?

Comment: This is `basic indexing` with 2 slices, applied to the 2 dimensions of the array, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basic-indexing.  The question of 'how', is ambiguous, since we don't know your understanding, or how detai,ed an answer you need.

Comment: @juanpethes, the alternatives he suggests, such as [3,:2], suggests he doesn't have a problem with the syntax.  But it's hard to tell.  `arr[2:4,:2]` is translated by the interpreter to `arr.__getitem__((slice(2,4,None), slice(None,2,None))`.  The interpreter can convert any `::` notation into slices, and is happy to pass a tuple to the object.  What happens next is class dependent.  `list` does not accept tuples. `numpy` does.  Details of what `numpy` does are hidden in compiled code, but the basic numpy index documentation is sufficient for most of us.

Comment: At a detailed level, this `basic indexing` produces a `view`, a new array, with a (2,2) shape,  same strides, and an offset pointer into the same databuffer.

Answer (score 1):

Asking 'how' is a bit ambiguous; just how much detail do you need?

```
In [222]: arr = np.arange(1,31).reshape(6,5)
In [223]: arr
Out[223]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [26, 27, 28, 29, 30]])
```

This part of the question suggests you are already ok with the 2 part array indexing: "[2, :3] for the [11, 12] and [3, :2] for [16, 17]", and are just confused by the seeming offsets.

But if we correct the first index, the pattern of selecting two rows, and two columns becomes more obvious:

```
In [224]: arr[2,:2]
Out[224]: array([11, 12])
In [225]: arr[3,:2]
Out[225]: array([16, 17])
```

Which can then be combined into one expression:

```
In [226]: x = arr[2:4, :2]
In [227]: x
Out[227]: 
array([[11, 12],
       [16, 17]])
```

With slices, this is `basic indexing`, and the result is a `view`:

```
In [228]: x.base
Out[228]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30])
```

That's the same `arange` that was reshaped to produce `arr` (which itself is a `view`).

We can explore that view a bit more with a dict display of the array properties:

```
In [229]: arr.__array_interface__
Out[229]: 
{'data': (93936282518720, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (6, 5),
 'version': 3}
In [230]: x.__array_interface__
Out[230]: 
{'data': (93936282518800, False),
 'strides': (40, 8),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}
In [231]: arr.strides
Out[231]: (40, 8)
```

The `x` array has the same strides, but smaller shape. The `data` value is a "pointer" to where the array 'starts' in that `arange` of numbers.  The `x` value has a 80 bytes offset (...800-...720).  That's `2*5*8` bytes in (2 rows of 8 bytes integers).  So that's all the indexing has to do: return a new array object, with these shape, strides, and data pointer values.

So in more detail:  `arr[2:4, :2]` is translated by the interpreter as a call to a `getitem` method, with a tuple of slices:

```
arr.__getitem__((slice(2,4,None), slice(0,2,None)))
```

So far this is standard python.  It's up to the array's own code to make sense of that tuple arguments.  A list would complain about the tuple, `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`, but numpy array's can use it.  (`numpy.index_tricks` has some classes that use this tuple trick to produce some psuedo-indexing syntax.)

More details on how to use basic indexing can be found at:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basic-indexing

We can pick the same values using arrays, but this is `advanced indexing`:

```
In [233]: arr[np.array([2,3])[:,None], np.array([0,1])]
Out[233]: 
array([[11, 12],
       [16, 17]])
```

and the result is no longer a view, it has it's own databuffer.  The indexing process in more complicated.

Comment: If `x` is of shape `(2,2)`, that means there are 4 8-byte numbers. That translates to 32 bytes (4 integers * 8 bytes per integer). Where does 80 bytes come from?

Comment: Is it not possible that the two views are simply stored at non-adjacent memory addresses?

Comment: @jared, the 80 bytes are the 10 numbers that come before 11 in the original array.

Comment: @jared, We need to distinguish between where the array object is stored, and where its data buffer is.  This 'data' entry 'points' to somewhere in the original data buffer, a C vector of bytes.  (It can't be used programmatically, that I know of. It isn't a `memoryview`.)  By the way, this particular view is not contiguous.  The first strides number is 40, where as the strides of the [233] copy is (16,8). A `ravel` of [227] will have to be a copy.

Comment: Do you have a link to where I can read up more on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

[2:4] selects rows 2 and 3 (the top row is 0).  The end of the range is always excluded, so row 4 is not selected.

[0:2] selects columns 0 and 1.

Comment: He asked why it works.

Comment: @juanpethes, actually he asked 'how'.  But even that is ambiguous.  He seems to have a partial, if slightly  mistaken, understanding.

Comment: Well, it said "why" before it was edited... but whatever - I agree the question is unclear

Comment: @juanpethes Sorry, the "how" vs "why" confusion is my fault. I had interpreted the original question to be "why" but the actual wording was "how".